# Format an answer for a specific programming language not mentioned in the question's tags

Tags: discussion

Consider the following Q&A (none of them mine btw):

[Hierarchical Agglomerative clustering in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44152337/hierarchical-agglomerative-clustering-in-spark?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The original question is not tied to any programming language. However one of the answers has extensive `scala` code:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/49122092/1056563 .  While it would be much easier to read the code if that tag were active, it would not make sense to update the question for that purpose.

Is there a mechanism for answer-specific syntax highlighting?

Comment: `<!-- language-all: lang-scala -->` assuming that prettifier exists. That will make all code blocks render as scala. Otherwise indicate per code block which prettifier should be used

Comment: thanks that works - the answerer did actually try but had the wrong identifier for scala